# Splash site fades out to index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to fade between pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(650);
    $("a:not([href^='#'])").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(650, redirectPage);      
    });       
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

And I use this script on my splash site the auto redirect to index page after 4 seconds:

```
var url ='buchstudio.html';
var delay = 4;
var d = delay * 1000;window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d);
```

The problem is that I want the splash site to fade in and after 4 seconds fade out and redirect to index page but at the moment it only fades in and on click fade out. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    var url = 'buchstudio.html';
    var delay = 4 * 1000;

    $('body').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(650);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(650, function(){
            window.location = url;
        });
    }, 4000)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to use code in a string. So I would keep to the norm and make a regular function inside setTimeout()

```
window.setTimeout (function() {parent.location.replace(url);}, d);
```